# IntelliJ 13 with SBT plugin does not recognize Scalding dependency

Tags: scala, intellij-13, scalding

I am trying to add Scalding 2.10 as a managed dependency via build.sbt like so:

```
name := "ss"

version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" % "scalding_2.10" % "0.10.0"
```

IntelliJ downloads the jar and adds it as an external library (see screen below) but fails to resolve the com.twitter namespace.

I have tried both invalidating the IntelliJ cache and generating project files via `sbt gen-idea` but neither solutions have worked.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The solution - remove project, invalidate cache and create project again. Sometimes intellij does not include libraries. You can run from console `sbt gen-idea`. Follow https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea instruction.

Answer (score 1):

The scalding jar file scalding_2.10 has no code in it to compile against. Its just 300 Bytes in size.

The correct dependency I feel should be

**libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" % "scalding-core_2.10" % "0.11.1"**

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggest try rm-ing your ivy2 cache, and try `sbt gen-idea`.  If that doesn't work, other things to check:

- makes sure you have indeed got the scala plugin installed.
- Most likely you're java SDK is not set or pointing somewhere wrong; right click the project dir, click "Open Module Settings", go to SDK and make sure the path is correctly set to the jdk otherwise syntax highlighting will likely break.

To test your deps have been properly pulled in from tinternet, try `sbt compile`; if it compiles then you should indeed have downloaded the dependency properly.